# Gutenberg editor styles not applied

Tags: block-editor, post-editor

Version 6.2.2.

I had make a 'row' in a post and i put it two image (horizontally and vertically centered), but it not work in live.
In get the Inspector, and i see that html-comment with json-styles, but it not applied to `.wp-block-group`, it displayed as `block` element, instead of `flex`.

- Is this operation correct?
- Should these comments appear in the source code?

If I eliminate `functions.php` and `style.css` in my theme, the problem persists.

**What do i have to do to make the styles apply and these editorial comments disappear?**

Thank you for your help in advance!

[image]

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: The latest blankslate theme.